# What happened to the Horn of Winter?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Does anyone know what happened to the horn? Since if I remember correctly it was shown in the tv show, found by Sam and I think he took it with him when he left south, or Idk if it was just in the books that he took the horn south, especially since from my understanding it should have been important to the plot of the Long Night, and I thought it would reappear.
Edit: A lot of people commented it did not appear in the tv show at all, I believed it was this one which made a lot of sense in my head.

https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Old_warhorn

Comment: I don't think Horn of Winter was ever a part of the show. The horn Sam took South was found on the Fist of the First men. It was not Horn of the Winter.

Comment: Oh, I was sure it was supposed to be the shows version of the horn of winter, was that discussed in the show at all, I don't remember it, so I thought it might be usefull in the future

Comment: I just assumed it had the same fate as dragonbinder, wipe out from the show

Comment: Are you asking about both the show and the book? It seems that your question relates to both, so it should be tagged with both [tag:game-of-thrones] (show) and [tag:a-song-of-ice-and-fire] (book)?

Comment: Just the show, I didn't remember exactly if he took or not the horn south with him like he did in the book, so that's why I referenced it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The horn of winter has not been referenced in the show at all, my guess is that in the books it was planned to play a part in allowing the others across the wall possibly by collapsing part of it, however in the tv series the dead dragon filled that plot hole. Now it is possible George Martin always intended the horn of winter to be a dead end plot and the dragon was always the way the wall would be breached, or maybe he will change this whole part of the story in the books. Until the books are released we will never know and even then we won’t know how much of the future story was lifted from the tv show rather then the tv show taking the original plans of the books.

Comment: Plot point, rather than plot hole, no?

Comment: If the books are released ...

Comment: I called it a plot hole because without the horn and insisting the dead can’t cross the wall because of “magic” (seriously what happened to all this cool magic anyway) the writers of the tv show may have suddenly gone, shit we need to bring the wall down, umm George what was your plan, a magical horn, you mentioned it in the books, um ok we need a new plan hmmmm Dragon.

Comment: The books will be released in wheel of time fashion after George R.R. Martin dies when the owners of his estate realize there is much moolah to be made.